# Firefox bookmark manager with two panes

Tags: gratis, firefox, bookmark

I regularly need to sort through and organize large amounts of bookmarks; e.g. moving entries from a long list into folders in another branch.
The built-in *Show all bookmarks* window doesn't help me enough, because I can only open it once<sup>*</sup>. I need to scroll up and down too much.

I'm looking for a free addin that lets me open two views/panes on my bookmarks, like many tools for handling files do:

[image]
<sup>(Total Commander example)</sup>

It would be great if the panes have multiselect, sorting and filtering capabilities.

<sup>* Even if you open two instances of FireFox, you can have only one bookmarks window</sup>

---

I have looked at [Bookmark Sorter](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/bookmark-sorter/?src=search) but this does not fit the bill: it displays all folders in an unsorted flat list, and its search option (with which I attempted to find a folder) searches only the bookmarks, not the folder names:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hack-R's answer suggestion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/38074/416) inspired me to use other keywords for my search and this helped me find [Total Bookmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/total-bookmarks).

This has exactly what I want, here is a screenshot of its window (you can also open it in a tab):

[image: Total Bookmarks extension screenshot]

The only serious drawback that I see to this add-on so far, is that it uses other key combinations than Total Commander. That will take some training.

It also has no search/filter features.

Comment: As of October 2020, this extension appears to be gone from AMO.  Does anyone know if it is still being developed, perhaps under a different name?

Answer (score 4):

At this time, there is the **Bookmarks Commander** [github repo here](https://github.com/brian-girko/bookmarks-commander)

for [Mozilla Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/bookmarks-commander/)

for [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-commander/knfpajocfeohpaipkfpdbfhgibajfmcf)

[image: Bookmarks Commander screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want **[2 Pane Bookmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/2-pane-bookmarks/)**. That's the literally the name of the add-on ;)

As the name implies, it's pretty much precisely what you described. Here's the description:

> This provides separated "Bookmarks" Sidebar panel like Opera.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (source: [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/2-pane-bookmarks/))</sup>

The preview of the add-on shows the panes being stacked vertically instead of horizontally. I'm not sure if that makes any difference to you, but it may be something you can customize anyway. Let me know how you like it.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I move one bookmark to another folder, the entire (source) list jumps to the top again - so it does not solve the *too much to scroll* issue.